# pgadmin 4.9 'int' object has no attribute 'replace' with editing text fields

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have just installed pgadmin 4.9 and am trying to edit several fields in my existing database. I right-click the table, select "View/Edit data" -> "All rows". Then in my table I change the data in a field of type "Text". When I then press the "Save" button, I get

```
'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Changing the field via an "Update" script works fine though.

Has anyone else experienced this?

This is on Windows 10 and pgadmin runs in MS Edge.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was a bug in pgAdmin4 when updating table and PK is of integer type.

It is fixed now and it will be available in next release, meanwhile you can use nightly build as a workaround.

Download: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/snapshots/2019-07-01/

**---- UPDATE ----**

pgAdmin 4 v4.10 is released with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Murtuza for this answer.

I wrote an [article](https://itanea.fr/apprendre-le-developpement-web/pgadmin-4-erreur-int-object-has-no-attribute-replace-postgresql/) (in french) about this problem, that I encountered with Laragon environment under Windows 10.

Hope it helps.

If you want it in English just ask me ;-)

See you

f-red